# Insert multiple rows into single mysql column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a form which dynamically creates new fields if the user wishes to. I am using post to retrieve all the values. However, I want to store and display all these values in a single column in a MySQL table.

What I did was create an array to store all these values. However I'm getting an error. Is this possible what I'm doing?

Storing post values in array:

```
$person1english[]=array("$english1","$english2","$english3","$english4","$english5","$english6","$english7","$english8","$english9","$english10");

$connect=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$db=mysql_select_db('conversationmaker');
if($connect)
{
    $sql="insert into relation(english_atom) values('$person1english');
    $query=mysql_query($sql);
    if($query)
    {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM relation";
        $query=mysql_query($sql);
        if($query)
        {

            echo "<table border=1>";
            echo "<tr><th>English</th><th>Sanskrit</th></tr>";
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {               
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row[1]."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";

        }
    }
  }
}
```

I am only working with English atm so you can ignore the row 2 that you see.

Comment: Your `insert` query is not closed. What error are you getting by the way?

Comment: "insert multiple rows into column" sounds like all kinds of wrong. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Comment: I know its not good practice from reading some other post. But what im trying to do, this is the only way i can do it. Im also new to php.

Comment: My error is:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'SELECT' (T_STRING)

Comment: very bad idea as Mike said, it will be hard and slow to process them later when needed.

Comment: If you're new how come you know it can't be done? :) Also it seems you're confusing field with column.

Comment: I can told you, you do not have " in the end of the insert query.

Comment: Ok i solved the previous error. Thanks for that. Now this is my error:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','  and i dont know how else to go about doing this.

Comment: That hardly tells us anything, does it mention the line number or near where? And you do realize `$person1english` is an array right? Inserting an array as a value would throw an error again.

Comment: first of all, in php array dont have to have [] in array declaration. If you want to use this bad design anyway,you need to use implode before insert.

Comment: the error occurs on line 92. which is the $persone1english[]=("$english1","$english2","$english3","$english4","$english5","$english6","$english7","$english8","$english9","$english10") and can you tell me what other methods there are?

Comment: did you checked this line $sql="insert into relation(english_atom) values('$person1english');

Answer (score 0):

use serialize() function

```
$person1english[]=array("$english1","$english2","$english3","$english4","$english5","$english6","$english7","$english8","$english9","$english10");

$connect=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$db=mysql_select_db('conversationmaker');
if($connect)
{
   $sql="insert into relation(english_atom) values('".serialize($person1english)."')";
```

use uunserialize() while fetching data from DB

Hope this help.
Thanks

Comment: I keep getting this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in  $person1english[]=("$english1","$english2","$english3","$english4","$english5","$english6","$english7","$english8","$english9","$english10");

Answer (score -1):

[Insert multiple rows with one query MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502032/insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query-mysql) -

here is your answer

OR you can also iterate over your array, i.e. with [foreach](http://hu1.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: he want to insert array elements inside same column, not multiple rows. If i understood him.