# How insert 700 records into mysql database with one query in php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have been trying with this for days i have 700+ records in a mysql database that i use a select query to get and then do some stuff to it. But when i want to reinsert the data it takes a long time to insert. How can i speed this up any help appreciated

```
       $zip_db_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'wa_zip_codes';

        $taxTable = $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_tax_rates";

        $taxTableLocation = $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_tax_rate_locations";   

        $getzip = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT zip FROM $zip_db_name ORDER BY zip DESC");

        foreach ($getzip as $retrieved_data){
            $zipcode = $retrieved_data->zip;                

            $url = 'http://dor.wa.gov/AddressRates.aspx?output=xml&addr=&city=&zip='. $zipcode .'';
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("feed not loading");

            foreach ($xml as $value){
                //data to be stored
                $country = 'US';

                $state = 'WA';                      

                $city = '*';

                $rate = $xml['rate'];   

                $wpdb->query("START TRANSACTION");          

                    // Inserts values into woocommerce_tax_rates                                                    
                    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $taxTable (tax_rate_country, tax_rate_state, tax_rate, tax_rate_name) VALUES ('$country', '$state', '$rate', '$city')");              

                    $thelastId = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT tax_rate_id FROM $taxTable ORDER BY tax_rate_id DESC LIMIT 1;");

                    //Gets the ID of the last inserted value in wpdb

                    $lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;

                    //Inserts zip code value into wp_woocommerce_tax_rate_locations

                    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $taxTableLocation (tax_rate_id, location_code, location_type) VALUES ('$lastid', '$zipcode', 'postcode')");                       

                $wpdb->query("COMMIT");
            }   
        }
```

Comment: Not possible as far as I'm aware. You may need a loop to insert it.

Comment: How would you construct that loop with what i already have. Thanks

Comment: Well assuming all your `values` are in an `array`, you'd do a `for loop` an have it loop through that array.

Comment: Currently the values are not in an array, if you could show an example of how to do this i would be greatful

Comment: people often insert 100 (or so) at a time, versus 1 at a time. much faster

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502032/insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query-mysql

Comment: Are you sure the insert's the slow part?  I think it's more likely to be the fact you're downloading data from an external site for each zip code.  Can you get the data for all zips in a single call, rather than doing them one at a time?

Comment: Other possible (slight) improvements - if `$country`, `$state`, and `$city` never change, only set them once, outside the loops.  And this loop `foreach ($xml as $value){` seems unnecessary - you never use `$value`.  If you're just checking the `$xml` is populated, an `if` statement makes more sense.  Finally, you're not using `$thelastId`.  I assume you think it's populating `$wpdb->insert_id`, but I doubt very much it is.  Try removing the line that sets it.  But really - I think the slow part is likely to be the external download (`simplexml_load_file`).

Comment: Hello Hobo thanks for your comment, could you explain how i would go about getting the zips in a single call

Comment: I don't know; it may not be possible.  It depends on the site that you're using to get the rates (http://dor.wa.gov/).  [The documentation](http://dor.wa.gov/content/findtaxesandrates/retailsalestax/destinationbased/clientinterface.aspx) seems to imply you need to provide a zip code, so you may be out of luck.  Maybe try using the contact form on that page and asking.