# Insert array connected to foreach loop into database

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, foreach, insert

First of all, I'm kinda new to this and don't know if the title is exactly what I'm asking for so I'll apologize in forehand. (I'm also Swedish so my English might not be perfect). And I looked at the "similar questions" but I didn't find anything of interest so far.

I have this foreach loop:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($ingredients as $ingredient) {

$ingredient_id = getIngredientId ($link, $ingredient);

if($ingredient_id != false) {
    insertRecipeIngredient($link, $recipe_id, $ingredient_id, $unit, $amount);
} else {
    $ingredient_id = insertIngredient($link, $ingredient);
}
$i++;
}
```

and I use this to insert the connection between recipe and ingredients in my database (and I want to insert the amount and unit of that ingredient):

```
function insertRecipeIngredient($link, $recipe_id, $ingredient_id) {
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO recipe_ingredients (recipe_id, ingredient_id, unit,
amount) VALUES ('$recipe_id','$ingredient_id', '$unit[$i]', '$amount[$i]'")); }
```

it says that the variables aren't defined (the unit and amount). I tried to echo out the whole thing inside of the foreach loop and it worked. So I guess that the extension with [$i] is right, but I don't know how to use it for the INPUT.

```
echo $amount[$i].' '.$unit[$i].' - '.$ingredient;
```

So the connection between the recipe(id) and the ingredients(id) are working just fine, but the amount and units doesn't wanna get into the database.

How am I suppose to insert those arrays into the database?

Do you need any more information?

Comment: Where is `$unit` coming from? You're not passing it in as an argument in your function.

Comment: all of the unit, amount, ingrediens, recipe information etc. if from a form. so $unit = $_POST['unit']. is that what you mean?

Comment: In your `insertRecipeIngredient()` function you are not passing in `$unit` as an argument so that function does not know what `$unit` is (unless you have it set as a global). It's also not passing in `$i` for that matter.

Comment: ^^ and inserting in a loop is a bad idea. concatenate and insert just once

Comment: Dagon, why is it bad to insert in a loop? how would I else insert an array?

Comment: You're also trying to use `$i` inside the function, but the scope of `$i` won't make it available inside the function. If you really want to use it inside `insertRecipeIngredient()` then you need to put `global $i` inside the function before you actually use it. You'll need to add `$unit` and `$amount` as globals as well if you're not going to send them to the function as an argument.

Comment: the less inserts the better (resource usage): as to how:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502032/insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query-mysql

Comment: Diddle Dot, so it should be function insertRecipeIngredient(..., $unit, $amount)? how will i know it's set as a global? I though anything inside the <?php ?> and outside anything else was a global? $unit $amount and $i are just in the <?php ?>

Comment: functions cannot access variables set outside themselves unless they're passed to the function as an argument, or defined as a global inside the function - so you'd have to go, `function insertRecipeIngredient($link, $recipe_id, $ingredient_id, $unit, $amount) { global $i; ... }` - just as a note, I'm not advocating this as the best method, but it will solve your problem without doing any major revisions. Alternative, you could just send $i to the function each time `function insertRecipeIngredient($link, $recipe_id, $ingredient_id, $unit, $amount, $i) {`

Comment: Drew, I'll try that.

Comment: `insertRecipeIngredient(..., $unit, $amount, $i)`

Comment: I did the `insertRecipeIngredient(..., $unit, $amount, $i)` .. but now I get : Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /m1/home/jonheh132/public_html/testing/form_process.php on line 45 . and that's the line for `mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO recipe_ingredients (recipe_id, ingredient_id, unit, amount) VALUES ('$recipe_id', '$ingredient_id', '$unit[$i]', '$amount[$i]'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your if statement to this:

```
if($ingredient_id != false) {
    insertRecipeIngredient($link, $recipe_id, $ingredient_id, $unit, $amount, $i);
}
```

And change that function to accept the `$unit`, `$amount`, and `$i` parameters

```
function insertRecipeIngredient($link, $recipe_id, $ingredient_id, $unit, $amount, $i)
```

Comment: Does it give you an error? If it does, is it the same one you mention before?

Comment: yes it's the same error. Here's my entire code: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=a1lu7t&s=9#.VsZV8hjoq8g

Comment: Take out the `global $i` and tell me what it does.

Comment: oh I forgot to take that one out before the screenshot. It's still the same error message.

Comment: Alter your `or die` part of the query to `or die(mysqli_errror($link))` and it should give you a more specific error.

Comment: i got `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

Comment: I was missing an ) ! I'll try!

Comment: It worked BUT it only post the first ingredient in the array, I inserted 3

Comment: It would probably be better to start a new question for that.