# How to insert an array into the database without inserting every loop in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have this array from the checkbox

```
<?php
    $query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM colors");
    while ($row = $query->fetch()) {?>
 <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" id="<?php echo $row['id']?>" value="<?php echo $row['hex'];?>">
<?php } ?>
```

PHP Query

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
    $query = $handler->query("INSERT INTO images (color_tags) VALUES ('$check')");
        }
    }
        ?>
```

I want to insert the data's from the array without inserting it on every row
I want it to be just separated in commas like   data1,data2,data3  then insert it.

Comment: just `implode` it, but why would need it like that

Comment: sorry i don't know about implode can you give me an example?

Comment: @Otachan I add answer, you can see my example of code and let me know if you have any further question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it in json.

```
json_encode($array)

<?php
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {

$query = $handler->query("INSERT INTO images (color_tags) VALUES ( json_encode($_POST['check_list']))");

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use implode() function. It join array elements with a string.

```
string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )
string implode ( array $pieces )
```

and save the string in database.

Comment: do i put that inside loop? or after?

Comment: If you are using implode than there is no need of looping, it convert your array to an string

Comment: Take care with the glue char. That char should not be the part of array string

Answer (score 1):

See answer in this post on how to insert multiple rows with one query in MySQL.  [Insert multiple rows with one query MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502032/insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query-mysql)

This code will create a single insert query for all the items in your checkbox array.

```
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    $insert_sql = "('".join("'),('",  $_POST['check_list'])."')";
    $query = $handler->query("INSERT INTO images (color_tags) VALUES ". $insert_sql);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check if count of posted array is greater than 0 or not, if it has then convert values into comma separated and insert it into table.Otherwise no need of conversion and not need to insert blank values into table

```
if(count($_POST['check_list']) > 0)
    $list = implode(",",$_POST['check_list']);
else
    $list = '';

$query = $handler->query("INSERT INTO images (color_tags) VALUES('$list')");
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not read your last line of require to keep it like a separated list. So, modifying my example

```
<?php

    if(!empty($_POST['check_list']) && is_array($_POST['check_list'])) {

      // use pipe "|" to separate values 
      $color_list = implode('|', $_POST['check_list']);

      // $handler -> mysqli or mysql
      $color_list = $handler->real_escape_string($city);
      $query = $handler->query("INSERT INTO images (color_tags) VALUES ('$color_list')");

    }
?>
```

Later you can use explode function to make it array again.

**Sudo Example**:

```
$DB_STRING_VALUE = "Fetch color_tags value from image table"
$list_of_colors = $DB_STRING_VALUE;

if(!empty($DB_STRING_VALUE)
  $list_of_colors = explode('|', $DB_STRING_VALUE);
```