# i want to insert two or more products to database when checkout button is clicked

Tags: php

I just want to insert all of the products records that are added to cart page. but when I press checkout button only one record is inserted and my query is like that. so if anyone could help me out please.

```
$sql = "insert into products (Product_id, Name) VALUES('$productid', '$name'  where Customer_id='$customer_session_id');
```

Comment: did you not bother reading manuals and how to use database functions' syntax?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **MySQL INSERT Syntax doesn't supports "Where"**.

Then, answering to your question, here is an example:
[Insert multiple rows with one query MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502032/insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query-mysql)

Comment: the link you have provided is not what i am lokiing for because o that link it shows manually but officially my website will be live so it should insert all of them which are selected from database

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your query.

1. The `WHERE` clause should be after the closing paranthesis because it is not one of the values that you want to insert.
2. If you want the `Customer_id` of your purchase to be set to `$customer_session_id`, you don't need a `WHERE` clause, you just insert it like all the other fields, for example `Product_id` and `Name`.
3. Concatenating values into the sql query like that is not safe, as you are vulnerable to SQL injection. I suggest you use PDO insetead.
4. You probably need to insert some sort of `$customer_id` instead of `$Customer_session_id`.

   ```
   <?php

   $server_name = "server_name";
   $db_name = "db_name";
   $username = "username";
   $password = "password";

   try {
       $db = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server_name ; Database = $db_name", $username, $password);
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage;
   }

   $sql = "insert into products (Product_id, Name, Customer_id) VALUES(:product_id, :name, :customer_session_id";
   $sth = $db->prepare($sql);

   foreach($products_in_cart as $product) {
       try {
           $result = $sth->execute($product);

           if($result === false) {
               echo $sth->errorInfo;
           }
       } catch (PDOException $e) {
           echo $e->getMessage();
       }
   }
   ```

This assumes:

1. The data for the db connection is correct and you are using SQL Server.
2. The table `products` has the fields `Product_id`, `Name` and `Customer_id`.
3. `$products_in_cart` has the following structure (but any values that are valid for the db table), including the keys used:

   ```
   $products_in_cart = [
       ["product_id" => "4928",
        "name" => "Fruit blender",
        "customer_session_id" => "1389"],
       ["product_id" => "0840",
        "name" => "Potato peeler",
        "customer_session_id" => "1389"],
       ["product_id" => "7348",
        "name" => "Set of forks",
        "customer_session_id" => "1389"]
   ];
   ```

If any of my asumptions isn't true, you can probably fix it without too much trouble.