# PHP, MYSQL code is not interacting with database

Tags: php, mysql

When I use to fill up all the fields and data the data isn't being updated on the MySql database , here is the PHP code

```
<?php
include("dbconnect.php");
$name=$_POST['name'];
$phn=$_POST['phnno'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$stuname=$_POST['stuname'];
$desc=$_POST['desc'];
if(empty($name)||empty($phn)||empty($stuname)||empty($email)||empty($desc)){
    header("location:status.php?val=0");
    die();
}
$sql="INSERT INTO feedback (name,phone,email,stuname,desc) VALUES ('$name','$phn','$email','$stuname','$desc')";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(!$result){
    header("location:status.php?val=1");
    die();
}
header("location:status.php?val=2");
```

the connection code is below

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', '********', '***********');
if (!$conn){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error($conn));
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($conn, 'davkeonj_app');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

> please don't mention about the $_POST security issues or others, i am
>   aware of them.
>   the redirects are sucessful but the data is not added

```
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oleo+Script:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Teko:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DAV PUBLIC SCHOOL</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li ><a href="http://davkeonjhar.org">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://davkeonjhar.org/admission">Admission</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://davkeonjhar.org/contact-us">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<section id="contact">
            <div class="section-content">
                <h1 class="section-header">Feedback</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-section">
            <div class="container">
                <form action="feedback.php" method="post">
                    <div class="col-md-6 form-line">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputUsername">Your name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder=" Enter Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail">Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder=" Enter Email id" required>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="telephone">Mobile No.</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phnno" placeholder=" Enter 10-digit mobile no." required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Student Name">Student name</label>
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="stuname" placeholder=" Enter student name" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for ="description"> Message</label>
                            <textarea  class="form-control" name="desc" placeholder="Enter Your Message" required></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit" name="submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Send Message</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
```

the above are the html codes for the page

Comment: what error you are getting with ?

Comment: Please post html code here

Comment: just the data arent updated in the table

Comment: use `print_r($_POST)`; and have look all value's are comming or not . use `die('here')` and debug your code line by line. nothing wrong with code. possible reasone is value not match with db structure

Comment: `echo $sql;` then you go in phpmyadmin, throw the sql, look and report what happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert multiple rows with one query MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502032/insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query-mysql)

Comment: thank you thomas for guiding . i found the solution, that was because i was using `desc` as the column name.

Comment: Yes desc is reserved key word the mysql