# Issue with Multiple table insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert the same data into two separate tables though I'm having issues with the syntax and I'm not sure how to correctly format everything. I know the queries work when run individually though when I try to run it as below I either get syntax errors or the last query runs and that's it.

```
$sql = "BEGIN TRANSACTION";
        "INSERT INTO users (user_name, first_name, last_name, email, password, hash) " 
        . "VALUES ('$user_name','$first_name','$last_name','$email','$password', '$hash')";
        "INSERT INTO tbluser (user_name, first_name, last_name, email, password, hash) " 
        . "VALUES ('$user_name','$first_name','$last_name','$email','$password', '$hash')";
        "COMMIT TRANSACTION";
```

Comment: What language is this for? The first problem might be that you're not concatenating (all) the string literals, at least if one assumes that it's a language using a C like syntax where `;` ends a line. And the next thing you should do is probably to look for parameterized queries in that language.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502032/insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query-mysql

Comment: Please mention your syntax error. And why . (dot) is in your SQL query before values.

Comment: Learn to use parameters!  Don't munge query strings with constant values.